# Check/Uncheck of mat-checkbox is not returning true or false properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working in `Angular 15` and `Angular Material 14` and below is the HTML code I am using as to display list of checkboxes

```
<div *ngFor="let control of checkboxArray.controls;let i = index" >
    <mat-checkbox [formControl]="control" (input)="validateInputs(notificationForm)" [checked]="control.value" (change)="control.checked=$event.checked;onCheckedChange(i);">
        {{ checkboxItems[i].name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

Below is the code of `onCheckedChange` function in Angular

```
onCheckedChange(index: number) {
    this.sortCheckboxArray();
    const checkboxItem = this.checkboxItems[index];
    const control = this.checkboxArray.at(index);

    if (control) {
      if (control.value) {
        this.lists.push(checkboxItem.id.toString());
      } else {
        this.lists.pop(checkboxItem.id.toString());
      }
    }
    this.updateSubscriberGroupsCount();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

While loading the checkboxlist controls, the names are disappearing for most of the controls as below...

When I check checkbox, then in this `onCheckedChange` function, the control.value is always returning false. Where it is going wrong? Could not understand..

**EDIT**

Below is my previous code for `addCheckbox` function

```
addCheckbox(id: number, name: string, checked: boolean) {
    const control = new FormControl(false);
    this.checkboxArray.push(control);

    const checkboxItem: SubscribersNotification = { id:id, name:name, checked: false };
    this.checkboxItems.push(checkboxItem);
}
```

With this checkbox controls are loading properly. But check/uncheck of the checkbox controls are not working..

How to modify this code so that it listens to the check/uncheck properly...

[image: Checkboxes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version, with the checkbox logic working fine, hope it helps!

We need to get the form group using `control.value`, but we also need to access the inner form control and then get the checkbox value!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MatCheckboxModule],
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div  formArrayName="array">
    <div *ngFor="let control of checkboxArray.controls;let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="test" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" 
    (change)="onCheckedChange(i);">
        {{ checkboxItems[i].name }}
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
</div>
</form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  form = new FormGroup({
    array: new FormArray([]),
  });
  lists = [];
  checkboxItems: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.add();
    this.add();
    this.add();
  }

  add() {
    this.checkboxArray.push(
      new FormGroup({
        test: new FormControl(false),
      })
    );
    this.checkboxItems.push({ name: 'test' });
  }

  get checkboxArray() {
    return this.form.get('array') as FormArray;
  }

  onCheckedChange(index: number) {
    // this.sortCheckboxArray();
    // const checkboxItem = this.checkboxItems[index];
    const control = this.checkboxArray.at(index);

    if (control) {
      if (control.value.test) {
        console.log('checked');
        // this.lists.push(checkboxItem.id.toString());
      } else {
        console.log('not checked');
        // this.lists.pop(checkboxItem.id.toString());
      }
    }
    // this.updateSubscriberGroupsCount();
    // this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-f2uacj?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: @CPK_2011 Have you tried my code change? could you check it once?

Comment: Who are you quoting? Please don't use blockquote formatting unless you are quoting at length (in which case you should cite your source).

Comment: @CPK_2011 please modify my stackblitz and share it back with the issue!, its difficult to debug with such less code!